# Reformat JSON arrays in MySQL database table using MySQL SELECT query (Wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, wordpress

I have a Wordpress build that uses CalderaWP forms. Unfortunately, the plugin's author has decided to store all checkbox entries as JSON arrays in the WP database and custom field values show up as "Array" instead of the actual text values.

I'd like to run a cron job that reformats these entries, but the first part is trying to figure out how to find and replace all values that are JSON objects.

I've written a function to get values from a specific table in the database, specifically the "wp_cf_form_entry_values" table.  This function uses a regular expression in the SELECT query to find all values that begin with the "{" character.  This is what I came up with to find JSON objects in the value field, but maybe there is a better way.  Anyway, the function gets these values and reformats them from a JSON object to a list of individual items (i.e. various values that were checked in the submitted form).

Here is my current function:

```
function reformat_my_data() {
    global $wpdb;
    $data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT value 
                                FROM `wp_cf_form_entry_values` 
                                WHERE `value` REGEXP '^[{].*$'
                                ");

    foreach($data as $key => $field) {

        foreach($field as $val) {
            if( is_json($val) ) {
                $val = json_decode($val, true);

                foreach($val as $checked) {
                    echo ' - ' . $checked . '<br/>';
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
reformat_my_data();
```

I also have another function to determine if the value is a JSON object:
`function is_json($string) {
    json_decode($string);
    return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}`

This works and outputs a list like this:
 - checked #1
 - checked #2
 - checked #3

**My question is: How do I get this newly formatted value back into the database?  In other words, how do I do a mass replace of JSON type objects in the WP database?**

Comment: Using `INSERT`? Or what is exactly special about your question to not use a normal SQL-Statement?

Comment: [`$wpdb->update('wp_cf_form_entry_values', ['value'=>'chkA,chkB'], ['id'=>$key]);`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows), or something along those lines.

Comment: @Andy, thanks for your comment.  The issue is that I have to check if the value is a JSON object.  That is what determines if I'll make any change to the value.  The issue is that there are 20+ multi-checkbox questions on this form that I've created and there could be endless variations.  So, I can't check by "value1, value2,etc.".  I need to check if the value is a JSON object.  If it is, then I need to reformat and replace it.

Comment: I think I don't get it right... Don't you just can add a `insert into`-Statement in your if and insert the formated value? You can use `$key`as the index.

Comment: For clarification: The multi-checkboxes can have multiple variations.  i.e. "answer1, answer2" or, "answer2, answer3, answer5" or "answer1, answer6, answer9", etc.  These are currently being stored in JSON format. i.e. {"answer2" , "answer3", "answer5"}.  I want to replace this JSON format with: answer2<br/>answer3<br/>answer5

Comment: Sorry, they are actually currently being stored in this format: {"opt1527807":"answer1","opt1735496":"answer3"}

Comment: Maybe it is possible to use `inserrt into` but I'm not sure how to use it.  If you think this would work, I would be eternally grateful for an example.